# How to Turn off Background Sound in Different Page when Option is Selected in Form

Tags: php, html, settings

I have two files `settings.php` and `main.php`. In main.php, there is background music playing that I know not everyone will like, but some do.

```
<bgsound src="theme.mp3" loop="5">
```

In settings, there is a form with two radio buttons that should turn it on or off, but I don't know how to do that.

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <fieldset>
  <legend>Application Settings</legend>
  <p>

  Background Music
    <label> <br />
    <input type="radio" name="Background Music" value="yes" id="Background Music_0" />
On</label>
    <br />
    <label>
     <input type="radio" name="Background Music" value="no" id="Background Music_1" />
 Off</label>
</form>
```

What is the best way to turn off the background music when the user returns to main.php?

Answer (score 0):

I would store everything in a session as soon as the user logs in. When settings are changed, both the database and the session should be updated and where you want to add the music, you just check for the appropriate session variable.